# symfony 1.4 reading relation 1:n doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-query

I want obtain the relations with two tables.

This is my schema.yml

```
Oferta:
  columns:
    titol: { type: string(50), notnull: true }
    sub_titol: { type: text }
    data_inici: { type: date }
    data_fi: { type: date }

Opcions:
  columns:
    oferta_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    descripco: { type: string(150), notnull: true }
    preu: { type: string(20), notnull: flase }
  relations:
    Oferta: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: oferta_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Opcions_FK}
```

The are this method: * @method Doctrine_Collection getOpcionsFK()  Returns the current record's "Opcions_FK" collection

And i have this code:

```
foreach ($ofertes as $oferta) { 


     echo $oferta->getId();
     $opcions = new Opcions(); 
    $opcions = $oferta->getOpcionsFK(); //this line do a error Unknown record property / related component "opcions_fk" on "Oferta"


}
```

The error:

public function filterGet(Doctrine_Record $record, $name)

```
{

    throw new Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException(sprintf('Unknown record property / related component "%s" on "%s"', $name, get_class($record)));

}
```

}

Someone know what don't runs it?

Thanks

Regards

Comment: could you post the complete error. Gràcies ;)

Comment: also: is the method getOpcionsFK autogenerated or defined by yourself? if defined by yoursef, could you show it?

Comment: is autogenerated. thanks

Comment: the only thing that could cause the error is that the `$oferta` variable is not an instance of the class `Oferta`. Can you check this?

Comment: public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    
   $this->ofertes =  Doctrine_Core::getTable('oferta')->createQuery("a")->execute();
   
  }

Comment: maybe this query returns no registers?

Comment: yes but i do foreach ($ofertes as $oferta)  and then $oferta is a register, is correct? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you name your foreignAlias "Opcions_FK" with uppercase ("K") and underscore may confuse Doctrine. Try to access directly to the property Opcions_FK of your Oferta:

```
foreach ($ofertes as $oferta) { 

   echo $oferta->getId();

   foreach($oferta->Opcions_FK as $opcions){

       echo $opcions->getOfertaId();

   } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@method Doctrine_Collection getOpcionsFK() Returns the current record's "Opcions_FK" **collection**

**Try:**

```
foreach ($ofertes as $oferta) { 

  echo $oferta->getId();

     foreach($oferta->getOpcionsFK() as $options){

       echo $options-> getOfertaId();
    } 
}
```